# Manage prometheus configuration using Prometheus operator

Tags: kubernetes-helm, prometheus-operator

I am looking for some recommendations as to how Prometheus configuration (like providing our custom alert rules files and reloading the config dynamically if the alert rules files sees some modifications ) using Prometheus operator (helm charts ) ??

Installing Prometheus using Prometheus operator generates default configuration for it so trying to custom feed it using values.yaml file of Prometheus operator.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Prometheus-Operator exposes CRD/s called PromethesRule/s. If you intend to provide your own custom rules, the best thing would be to start out with some simple rules just to get used to the vector centered language PromQL. Also you could expose Prometheus Web UI just to get used to the interface, have a look at metrics, play with the console, evaluate your targets ...

You do not have to worry about rules being picked up, it happens automatically if everything is fine with your Targets and also the TCP/IP needed ports are opened.

Also in case your face some challenge their github page is quite responsive and they have a 'support' label for opened features.

Comment: Thank you Recoba for your valuable response. 
The idea is to produce the alert rules files from our application based on the metrics we want to monitor and expect it to be picked by Prometheus at runtime. Of course any modifications to this file is expected to reload the prometheus configuration too. 

So basically no web ui is involved.